# How to check if the uploaded file is a supported file

Tags: php, image, getimagesize

i'm uploading a **tif** file, but i always get the echo 'The uploaded file type is not supported'. Why?
How do i check if file is supported according to my array of supported files

```
//image types supported
$types = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_TIFF);

list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']);
$ext = image_type_to_extension($type); // get the extension

if (!isset($types[$type])) {
   echo = 'The uploaded file type is not supported';
} else
   echo = 'All good!';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if `$types` has a key `$type` rather than a value `$type`. Instead use in_array.
Also form http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php, there is no `IMAGETYPE_TIFF` but instead `IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II` and `IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM`

```
$types = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II, IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM);
...
if (in_arry($type,$types)) {
```

Comment: that did it! thanks... just corrected the mispelling: if (!in_array($type, $types)) {...}

Answer (score 2):

I think your TYPE is not correct try the following types.

```
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II     => 'tiff',        ###  7 = TIFF     (intel byte order)
IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM     => 'tiff',        ###  8 = TIFF     (motorola byte order)
```